# Call a Get Method from Another Form, C#

Tags: c#, class, methods

I am sorry if my question is silly , I am a beginner.I have two forms:

- Form1: Displays a Table of Information
- Form2: Displays a Form to Fill information

I need to get the information in Form2 to Form1 Using get methods (If there is a better way please suggest it).

My problem is that when I type those get methods in Form1 they are not recognized.

Form1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //---------------------------------Initial Stuff------------------------------------
        Form2 form2 = null;

        //----------------------------------Constructor-------------------------------------
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void nouveau_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (form2 == null)
            {
                form2 = new Form2();
                form2.Show();
            }
        }

        //---------------------------------ListView of Information------------------------------
         ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(getClient());
            lvi.SubItems.Add(societe.Text);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(datedebut.Text);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(type.Text);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(etat.Text);

            
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : 
    {
        
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            
            client.Text="";
            societe.Text = "";
            datedebut.Text = "";
            type.Text = "";
            etat.Text = "";
            
            
        }
        //----------------------------Return Functions for table----------------------
        
        public String getClient()
        {
            return client.Text;
        }
        public String getSociete()
        {
            return societe.Text;
        }
        public String DateDebut()
        {
            return datedebut.Text;
        }
        public String getType()
        {
            return type.Text;
        }
        public String getEtat()
        {
            return etat.Text;
        }
        
    }
}
```

---

So I update my code and tried another way to do things

Now I have 4 .cs files: Principal, FillInfo, Folder, Program

Program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Principal());
        }
    }
}
```

Folder:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class Folder
    {
        //-----------------------------------------CONSTRUCTOR--------------------------
        public Folder()
        {
            this.Customer = "";
            this.Company = "";
            this.StartDate = "";
            this.TechUsed = "";
            this.Status = "";
        }

        //-----------------------------------------GETTERS AND SETTERS-------------------
        public string Customer { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string StartDate { get; set; }
        public string TechUsed { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }

        
    }
}
```

Principal:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Principal : Form
    {
        
        
        //-----------------------------------INITIAL VARIABLES--------------------------------------------------

        FillInfo fillinfo = null;
        public Folder f;
        
        
        

        //-----------------------------------INITIAL METHODS----------------------------------------------------

        public Principal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
                
        //-----------------------------------ELEMENTS METHODS--------------------------------------------------
        
        // NEW BUTTON
        private void pNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            f= new Folder();
            
            if (fillinfo == null)
            {
                fillinfo = new FillInfo();
                fillinfo.Show();
            }
        }
        
        //---------------------------------------PROCESSING-----------------------------------------------------

         ListViewItem fillInfoListView = new ListViewItem(f.getCustomer());
         

    }
}
```

FillInfo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class FillInfo : Form
    {
        //-----------------------------------INITIAL VARIABLES--------------------------------------------------
        
        //-----------------------------------INITIAL METHODS----------------------------------------------------
        
        public FillInfo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //-----------------------------------ELEMENTS METHODS--------------------------------------------------
        
        private void fOkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            


            f.setCustomer = fCustomerTextField.Text;
            f.setCompany = fCompanyTextField.Text;
            f.setStartDate = FStartDateDatePicker.Text;
            f.setTechUsed = fTechUsedDropList.Text;
            f.setStatus = fStatusDropList.Text;

            fCustomerTextField.Text = "";
            fCompanyTextField.Text = "";
            FStartDateDatePicker.Text = "";
            fTechUsedDropList.Text = "";
            fStatusDropList.Text = "";
            
        }
     
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using individual methods to expose data instead passing around a single model object?

Comment: **Give your forms proper names**. `Form1` and `Form2` are undescriptive and unhelpful names for forms - and give your project a proper name instead of `WindowsFormsApplication1`. Also, you should also use `this.` when referring to instance members so people reading your code can instantly tell what identifiers are form members vs. statics vs. locals/parameters.

Comment: oh yes, it's better, I will try that , thank you

Comment: C# has properties. Don't use methods when you actually mean to use properties. A property isn't a shortcut for getters and setters for fields, it's part of an object's API surface. Fields are just implementation details. All libraries expect properties: serializers work on properties, data binding on Windows Forms or WPF works on properties (which is what you need here), validation works on properties.

Comment: thank you @PanagiotisKanavos, I am re-writing the code to use propreties instead of getters and setters, thank you, that was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Form2 is something that appears and asks the user for info, then disappears when the user is done typing into it, it would probably look like:

```
    private void nouveau_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form2 = new Form2();
        form2.ShowDialog();   //SHOW DIALOG

        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(getClient());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(form2.Societe);   //the property you are busy writing
        lvi.SubItems.Add(form2.DateDebut); //the property you are busy writing
        lvi.SubItems.Add(form2.Type);      //the property you are busy writing. Try and think of a more hepful name than Type
        lvi.SubItems.Add(form2.Etat);      //the property you are busy writing

        //do you need to add that lvi to something?
    }
```

Remove Form2 from being a class level variable

Comment: Thank you very much,
I will add lvi to ListView1 which is the table that is in designer
Form2 was created as a class automatically and I need to use the designer, how do I use the designer without creating Form2 as a Class ? sorry if im slow

Comment: Going back to Dai's comment about naming things - when you drop a control on a form rename it (listView1 -> societiesListView). If Microsoft adopted a practice of "call everything by its type and an incrementing number depending on when it was added to the code" then C# programming would be a very weary experience: we wouldn't have `DateTime.Now, DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.Year, DateTime.Month` etc we would have `DateTime.DateTime1, DateTime.DateTime2, DateTime.Int1, DateTime.Int2` and no code would make sense

Comment: yes, I will do that, I was just testing the functionnality that's why I didn't bother to rename them, I will rename them now so that it's more clear

Comment: *how do I use the designer without creating Form2 as a Class ?* - er.. When you use the designer you're developing (i avoid the word "creating" deliberately) Form2 as a class - youre drawing things and Visual Studio is busy writing hundreds of lines of code in FormX.Designer.cs. When you want to *use* that class to do something useful, you need to create a `new` instance of it, show it, let the user click it. The answer to exactly the question asked is "you can't *use the designer* and also *not create a class*" - creating classes is what the designer does. I suspect you meant something else

Comment: _Remove Form2 from being a class level variable_ , this is what I meant, by _you can't use the designer and also not create a class_, the designer creates it as a class, how do I remove if from being a class lever variable, thank you very much for your help

Comment: You delete the line of text `Form2 form2 = null;` under "Initial Stuff". A "class level variable" is another name for "field" - a variable declared inside a `class` but not inside a method: `class X{ string iAmAClassLevelVariable = ""; public void SOmeMethod(){ var iAmAlocalVariable = "" } }`

Comment: Ah okay, I understand now,  thank you , then I will try to polish my code and and try that solution, thanks a lot

Comment: how do I show my modified code, should I just edit the post @Caius Jard

Comment: I wouldn't edit the question so much that it invalidates the answer, but if you want to hit Edit on the question, put `---` at the bottom and then under it write clearly that you've updated the code and what it is now then i can do the same.. BUT if it's changed so that youre actually asking a totally new question about an unrelated problem, like some compiler error, then you should aska  new question

Comment: I have tried another solution but it still doesn't work, can you check it please ?

Comment: Honestly, it doesn't appaer that you've implemented any of the advice I gave